# Converting XML to SQL Server Table using C# (or any other method)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml

I have about 10,000 XML files where I need to convert them into SQL table.

However, here are the problems, each XML files has some variations between each other thus it is almost impossible for me to specify the element name. For example:

```
//XML #1
<color>Blue</color>
<height>14.5</height>
<weight>150</weight>
<price>56.78</price>

//XML #2
<color>Red</color>
<distance>98.7</distance>
<height>15.5</height>
<price>56.78</price>

//XML #3: Some of the elements have no value
<color />
<height>14.5</height>
<price>78.11</price>

//XML #4: Elements has parent/child
<color>
    <bodyColor>Blue</bodyColor>
    <frontColor>Yellow</frontColor>
    <backColor>White</backColor>
</color>
<height>14.5</height>
<weight>150</weight>
<price>56.78</price>
```

With the example above, I should expect a table created with `columns` name: `color, height, weight, price, distance` (Because XML #2 has distance), `bodyColor, frontColor, backColor`.

Expected output:

```
XML#    color    height    weight    price    distance    bodyColor    frontColor    backColor
1       Blue     14.5      150       56.78    NULL        NULL         NULL          NULL
2       Red      15.5      NULL      56.78    98.7        NULL         NULL          NULL
3       NULL     14.5      NULL      78.11    NULL        NULL         NULL          NULL
4       NULL     14.5      150       56.78    NULL        Blue         Yellow        White
```

In this case, NULL or empty value are acceptable.

These are just examples, there are at least 500 elements in each XML file. Also, even though I mentioned C# here, if anyone can suggest a better way of doing so, please let me know.

Comment: Get the files to follow a certain Xml Schema Definition. It is ok for tags to be empty or NULL. It is important for the tag to be present. Then it will be easier to work with the file.

Comment: @abhi What do you mean by XML Schema Definition? (Sorry, I'm quite new to XML)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_intro.asp @C.J.

Comment: One possible solution would be to iterate over every XML file and extract all unique fields and create a table in the database with all of the extracted unique fields. This way you would know what fields you have so that you could perhaps consider to normalize the table(s) later.

Comment: @Hituptony I was about to post the [same link](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_schema.asp).

Comment: @abhi it aint easy bein greazy

Comment: @abhi and Hituptony: So I guess my next question is, how do I generate the schema?

Comment: @pasty You're right, I won't even think of normalization at this point (probably later). Is there any good method to loop through every single XML file to extract unique fields like you mention?

Comment: You could get a sample file that has all the possible tags. Then Visual Studio will create the XSD for you. There are other tools in the market that are better at this game. Altova XML SPY and Liquid come to mind. In 2011, I was working on a very similar activity.

Comment: @abhi thank you for the info, I will do some research on them

Comment: You could quite easily build one table with three columns `filename` `nodename` and `value` using tsql and xquery. If that is not good enough you could some dynamic pivot over that table to get one row for each imported file with all possible columns. If you have more than one row of data per file you need another column to be able to regenerate the row in the pivot query.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson It is confirmed that one XML = one row. However, xquery requires you to specify the path when doing the query. First, I may not know what the nodes may present inside each XML, second, example above, <color> is a node with a value itself in XML #1, but in XML #4, <color> is just a parent node. How am I going to write a dynamic query based on these?

Comment: `//*` gives you all nodes and the you use `local-name()` to get the node name and `text()` to get the value for that node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility to iterate over all xml files and get all unique tags could use [LINQ2XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx), the [HashSet class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and could look like this:

```
try
{
    // add as many elements you want, they will appear only once!
    HashSet<String> uniqueTags = new HashSet<String>();
    // recursive helper delegate
    Action<XElement> addSubElements = null;
    addSubElements = (xmlElement) =>
    {
        // add the element name and 
        uniqueTags.Add(xmlElement.Name.ToString());
        // if the given element has some subelements
        foreach (var element in xmlElement.Elements())
        {
            // add them too
            addSubElements(element);
        }
    };

    // load all xml files
    var xmls = Directory.GetFiles("d:\\temp\\xml\\", "*.xml");
    foreach (var xml in xmls)
    {
        var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(xml);
        // and take their tags
        addSubElements(xmlDocument.Root);
    }
    // list tags
    foreach (var tag in uniqueTags)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(tag);
    }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
}
```

Now you have the *columns* for the *basic* SQL table. With little enhancing, you could also mark the parent and the sub nodes. This could help you for the normalization.

Comment: You gave me a head start, however, I have just discovered even more issues in the XML. I have issues where in just one XML, it has elements like: `<color>Red</color> <color>Blue</color> <color>Green</color>` These are 3 different colors, but because of the unique filter, it only returns `color` 1 time instead of 3.

Comment: That is why you probably need to consider also the *nesting* level, so that you can add *subelements* with the same name too. You need anyway to analyse the whole input data. For example it could be ok, that nested color-tags are renamed to `bodyColor`, `frontColor` and so on or to something more appropriate like `blueComponent`.

Comment: thank you anyway, at least your code gave me a head start, I will modify it to fit the condition I need

Comment: Glad that the answer helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in TSQL using xQuery, a staging table and dynamic pivot.

Staging table:

```sql
create table dbo.XMLStage
(
  ID uniqueidentifier not null,
  Name nvarchar(128) not null,
  Value nvarchar(max) not null,
  primary key (Name, ID)
);
```

`ID` is unique per file, `Name` hold the node name and `Value` the node value.

Stored procedure to populate the staging table:

```sql
create procedure dbo.LoadXML
  @XML xml
as

declare @ID uniqueidentifier;
set @ID = newid();

insert into dbo.XMLStage(ID, Name, Value)
select @ID,
       T.X.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)'),
       T.X.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
from @XML.nodes('//*[text()]') as T(X);
```

`//*[text()]` will give you all nodes that have a text value

Dynamic query to unpivot the data in the staging table:

```sql
declare @Cols nvarchar(max);
declare @SQL nvarchar(max);

set @Cols = (
            select distinct ',' + quotename(X.Name)
            from dbo.XMLStage as X
            for xml path(''), type
            ).value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'nvarchar(max)');

set @SQL = '
select '+@Cols+'
from dbo.XMLStage
pivot (max(Value) for Name in ('+@Cols+')) as P';

exec sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Try it out in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f9594/1)